# How to get rid of space between buttons and content/paragraph? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am making a manual with html/css/js and to go through the manual I made two buttons.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

**The strange this is, the first previewed menu-item 'introductie' has the same css code as the fourth previewed menu-item 'hart meten'. But why is there a gap between the paragraph and the buttons in the previewed 'introductie' ?**

my code:

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Hartmeting</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>

            <div id="logo" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/Zorg_Heartbeat%20Manual/'">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                <h1 >Hartmeting voor fitte mensen</h1>
            </div>

        </header>

        <!-- Stappenplan Menu -->
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>

                <li><a href="#menu_a"> Introductie </a></li>
                <li><a href="#menu_b"> Het Probleem </a></li>
                <li><a href="#menu_c"> Stappenplan </a></li>
                <li><a href="#menu_d"> Hartmeting </a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

        <!-- HET STAPPENPLAN -->
        <div id="content">

            <!-- Intro Slide -->
            <article id="menu_a">
                <h2>Introductie</h2><br>
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/intro1.jpeg" alt="Intro Afbeelding"/>
                </figure>
                <p>Joggers zijn actieve mensen die graag tussen werk en/of studie nog even de kilometers willen pakken. Hierin houden ze graag bij of ze fitter worden of niet, zo zul je vaak zien dat joggers hun rusthartslag meten om een indicatie van positieve 'progress' te kunnen inzien. Het bijhouden van de gezondheid hoort eigenlijk niet alleen bij joggers, maar bij elk fit persoon die graag de resultaten wilt vastpakken. Zonder dat je een smartwatch nodig hebt, kun je met elk apparaat die beschikking heeft tot het internet, je hartslag meten!</p>
            </article>

            <!-- Slide 1 -->

            <article id="menu_b">
                <h2>Het Probleem</h2><br>
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/hetprobleem1.jpg" alt="Eerste Afbeelding"/>
                </figure>
                <p>Maar waarom een WebApp die je hartslag meet? Simpel, smartwatches zijn nou eenmaal veels te duur, je gebruikt ze niet altijd en daarnaast zijn ze de meeste ook nog eens privacy gevoelig.</p>
            </article>

            <!-- Slide 2 -->

            <article id="menu_c">
                <h2>Hoe kan mijn hartslag meten?</h2><br>
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/polsmeten.png" alt="Tweede Afbeelding"/>
                </figure>

                <ol id="stappen">
                    <li>Ga gerust zitten.</li>
                    <li>Houd je wijsvinger en middelvinger tegen elkaar.</li>
                    <li>Leg beide vingers links of rechts van de adamsappel (zoek naar een kloppende beweging).</li>
                    <li>Klik met je linker muisknop op de box elke keer dat je een klopping voelt.</li>
                    <li>Doe dit achtereenvolgend tot dat je 10 keer hebt geklikt (dus 10 kloppingen).</li>
                    <li>De pop-up laat je gemiddelde hartslag per minuut zien.</li>
                </ol>


            </article>

            <!-- Slide 3 -->    

            <article id="menu_d">

                <h2>Hart Meten</h2><br>
                <figure>
                    <!-- Hartmeet tool -->
                        <div id="klik_Hart" class="heart">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <!-- Einde hartmeet tool-->
                    </figure>

                    <ol id="stappen">
                        <li>Een normaal rustend hart van een volwassenen meet tussen de 60 - 100 hartslagen per minuut.</li>
                        <li>Boven de 100 is slecht.</li>
                        <li>Richting de 40 is goed.</li>
                    </ol>

                </article>

                <!-- ABOUT -->
                                    <!-- <div id="about">

                                        <p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST </p>

                                    </div> -->


                                    <!-- vorige/volgende buttons -->
                                    <table id="volgorde">
                                        <th><button class="button" id="previous">Previous</button></th>
                                        <th><button class="button" id="next">Next</button></th>
                                        <th>
                                            <!-- Checkbox Auto Slider -->   
                                            <div class="auto_menu">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
                                                <label for="checkbox">Auto Handleiding</label>
                                            </div> 
                                            <!-- -->
                                        </th>   
                                    </table>

                                <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                <p> Wij zijn ....</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>


                                </div>
                                <div id="buffer"></div>
                                <footer>
                                <a  id="footer_" href="#" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Over ons </a>
                                </footer>

                            </div>

                            <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
                            <script src="js/scripts1.js" type='text/javascript'></script>


                        </body>

                        </html>
```

**CSS**

```
#titel{ color: #B0C4DE; text-align: center;}

/*Verstop alle artikelen binnen content*/
article {
    display:none;
}

body{

    background-color: #333333;
    color: grey;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 100%%
}

#wrapper{

    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left top;
    border: 2px groove #001f3f;
    overflow: auto;

}

#content{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

#content img{

    height: 250px;
    width: 450px;
}

#menu{

    font-weight: thin;
    color: #424242;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 6.7%;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

    ul{list-style-type: none;}

    h1{ text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #00008B;}

    a{
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #0074D9;
        background-color: #001f3f;
        border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
        padding: 5px;

    }

    a:hover{
        background-color: #FFD900;
        color: #001f3f;
    }

    footer{
        overflow: hidden;
        clear: both;
    }

    #volgorde{
        font-weight: thin;
        color: grey;
        width: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        clear: both;
        margin-left: 3%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .button {
        background-color: #001f3f; 
        color: #FFDC00;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 30px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
        display: block;
    }

    .button:hover{
        background-color: #FFD900;
        color: #001f3f;
    }

    .heart{
        color:#FBF9FF;
        background-image: url("../img/hart4.png");
        background-size: 150px 150px;
        height: 150px; 
        width: 150px;
    }

    .heart:hoover{
        color: #FFA07A;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    #uitleg p {
        color: #FA8072;
    }

    #logo img {
        float: left;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        margin-left: 2%;

    }

    #logo h1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 15px;
        left: 10px;
    }

    #klik_ {
        text-align: center;
    }

    article p {

        height: 200px;
        width: 450px;
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: grey;
        font-weight: bold;
        overflow: scroll;
        margin-left: 4%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        text-align: justify;
        text-justify: inter-word;
    }

    #buffer{
        clear: both;
        height: 10%;
    }

    #stappen{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    .auto_menu {
        position: relative;
        margin: 5px auto;
        width: 160px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }


    /*OVER ONS OVERLAY*/

    .overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

**EDIT: Web Inspector Shows:**

[Screenshot showing findings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c66ha.png)

So I think it might be:

```
margin-bottom: 5%;
```

when I deleted this, nothing happened..

Comment: Inspect the offending element in the browser's "inspect element" function, and you will see what causes the gap - padding, margin, something like that.

Comment: fix your13 html errors by checking here. paste your code https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea  then once you edit your html try again

Comment: @mlegg thanks I did not know this, I will fix the 13 errors and come back.

Comment: @mlegg I reduced the errors to about 3-5 errors. Still it shows the gap.

Comment: You can very easily detect what this is, it's inspecting the element, you are able to do this on every browser. On chrome ( `ctrl`+ `schift` + `i`) and it will open, then you can go through your elements and see what causes it to not be up there, my guess is `padding`.

Comment: @Nytrix I will try it out now, thanks

Comment: @Nytrix Please see my Edit.

Comment: @user7186746 As schown in your screenshot, there is some `margin` from the `top` and `bottom` and a lot from the `right`. You can for instance say: `margin-bottom: 0px` then there will be no margin of the bottom, then the next element will be right below it. Also, your design changed when in the inspector mode, this means it's very `absolutly` designed, on other `web-browsers`, `phones` etc, the design will change, as also seen in the `screenshot`

Comment: @Nytrix True it's not responsive yet. But I tried the margin-bottom: 0px option. But yeah, too bad nothing worked. I think I am going to give up. Thanks for all your help bro!

Comment: @user7186746 You can solve it, it's probably the whole `article` that has a pre-set `height`. Use the `inspect element` tool and hover over all the elements involved, eventually you will see the space filled in a color. Orange/red means `margin`, green means `padding`.

Comment: @user7186746 I have found the problem. `p` has `200px` `height` set to them, so it's `200px` heigh, no matter how much content. You can change that to `height: auto; display: inline-block;` this will make it as heigh as the content makes it.

Comment: @Nytrix You did it ! I did not know height: auto; display: inline-block; yet, I am very new to css. I come from PHP. Thank you so much man!  I learned alot. Is there a way to keep the space between the  buttons and the text static for each menu-item? I think putting padding on the id 'content' and that of the buttons.. I will try that out. Also how can I choose your answer as the 'winner'?

Comment: You are welcome, fellow dutchie! You should look into `margin` for that, there are more advanced methods with `positions` to. The more `general` you write `css` the better, it will be less work and it will work over more devices and such.

Comment: @Nytrix, nice gast, topper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the `height` of your `p`. That means that your `element` will always stay at the `height` of `200px`, no matter the content inside the `element`.

In order to change that to a `dynamic` `height` change it to:

```
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
```

The code is pretty straight forward, you display what is within the block. The height is automatically adjusted depending on the `inline` of that `block`.